# Returning SQL values for all fields with another value - if yet another value is present

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with Oracle (again), and as a relative beginner, was hoping someone could advise.

We have an Assyst database with several tables. What I'm trying to do is report all entries in act_reg where the incident.incident_id is present - but ONLY if there is at least one occurrence of a particular serv_dept_id in that act_reg.

Clear as mud I know.

I've been trying a WHERE EXISTS clause, however it only seems to return the row if the row specifically contains the serv_dept_id I'm looking for, not where just the incident_id matches. Not all entries with the incident_id if it is present one or more times.

In the example below there's a small amount of pseudo code (the two select lines of Action and Team), because they're linked to other tables, and outside the scope of the request.

```
select incident.incident_ref "Call Ref",
act_reg.date_actioned "Date Actioned",
    act_reg.action "Action",
    act_reg.team "Team"
from incident, act_reg

where incident.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id
and exists (
     SELECT jptsys_svd_group.svd_group_id
     FROM serv_dept act_svd_2, jptsys_svd_group
     WHERE act_svd_2.serv_dept_id = act_reg.serv_dept_id
     AND act_svd_2.svd_group_id = jptsys_svd_group.svd_group_id
     AND jptsys_svd_group.svd_group_sc = 'TEAM 1 GROUP'
    )
```

What I'm expecting is (let's say Team 1 is in Team 1 Group above, but no other team is):

```
 Call Ref | Date Actioned | Action     | Team
 --------------------------------------------
 27       | 01/01/2019    | Assign     | Team 1
 27       | 01/01/2019    | Update     | Team 2
 27       | 02/01/2019    | Info       | Team 2
 27       | 02/01/2019    | Close      | Team 1
```

What I'm getting is:

```
 Call Ref | Date Actioned | Action     | Team
 --------------------------------------------
 27       | 01/01/2019    | Assign     | Team 1
 27       | 02/01/2019    | Close      | Team 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Sample data below:

```
 Call Ref | Date Actioned | Action     | Team
 --------------------------------------------
 27       | 01/01/2019    | Assign     | Team 1
 28       | 01/01/2019    | Create     | Team 3
 29       | 01/01/2019    | Create     | Team 4
 27       | 01/01/2019    | Update     | Team 2
 27       | 02/01/2019    | Info       | Team 2
 31       | 02/01/2019    | Update     | Team 2
 27       | 02/01/2019    | Close      | Team 1
```

What I would like to see is all rows for a call ref, if (in this case), Team 1 has performed an action on it. So in the above sample data, this would return all rows with call ref 27 because team 1 is present in some of the rows with that reference.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Sample data added and desired results (hope it's clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to achieve your aim - here I use `MAX() OVER ()`, but you could do it with `COUNT() OVER ()` if you wanted:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 27 call_ref, to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Assign' action, 'Team 1' team FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 28 call_ref, to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Create' action, 'Team 3' team FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 29 call_ref, to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Create' action, 'Team 4' team FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 27 call_ref, to_date('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Update' action, 'Team 2' team FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 27 call_ref, to_date('02/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Info' action, 'Team 2' team FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 31 call_ref, to_date('02/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Update' action, 'Team 2' team FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 27 call_ref, to_date('02/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_actioned, 'Close' action, 'Team 1' team FROM dual)
SELECT call_ref,
       date_actioned,
       action,
       team
FROM   (SELECT call_ref,
               date_actioned,
               action,
               team,
               MAX(CASE WHEN team = 'Team 1' THEN team END) OVER (PARTITION BY call_ref) team_interested_in
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE  team_interested_in = 'Team 1';

  CALL_REF DATE_ACTIONED ACTION TEAM
---------- ------------- ------ ------
        27 01/01/2019    Assign Team 1
        27 01/01/2019    Update Team 2
        27 02/01/2019    Info   Team 2
        27 02/01/2019    Close  Team 1
```

This works by converting the team into either `Team 1` (the value we're interested in) or NULL. Then we find the MAX value and apply that across all rows in the group (which is based on call_ref).

If Team 1 appears in any of the rows, our new column will contain Team 1 for all rows, meaning we can filter on that column.

Comment: Thank you so much, that does the trick (marked as answer), but having trouble fitting it into my query. I have some other WHERE statements - do these go alongside `WHERE team_interested_in` is now?

Comment: So, you can see that I used an inline view (aka a subquery in the `FROM` clause) to generate the results with the analytic function - that's the bit you'd need to update for your query, and then you filter based on the team_interested_in column afterwards. I.e. where I've used `your_table` in the subquery, you'd replace with your actual table(s) and joins etc. You obviously don't need the `with your_table as (...)` bit, unless you want to plonk your main query in there.

Comment: Got you. Got it working now! Phew, hope I never have to do that again. Much appreciation, thank you.

Comment: You'll know what to do next time you come across this scenario! *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your `WHERE EXISTS` clause is correlating to the `act_reg.serv_dept_id` of the row in the main section and it sounds like that's not what you want. Assuming `incident_id` is not in these other two tables (it would help to see the structure of all tables in the query), you have to pull `act_reg` in again. Try this for the `EXISTS` clause:

```
and exists (
     SELECT jptsys_svd_group.svd_group_id
     FROM serv_dept act_svd_2, jptsys_svd_group, act_reg AS ACT_REG2
     WHERE ACT_REG2.incident_id = act_reg.incident_id
     AND act_svd_2.serv_dept_id = ACT_REG2.serv_dept_id
     AND act_svd_2.svd_group_id = jptsys_svd_group.svd_group_id
     AND jptsys_svd_group.svd_group_sc = 'TEAM 1 GROUP'
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work I'm afraid. I get results, but they're the same as before, only entries where the team group is TEAM 1 GROUP in `incident_id`

Comment: A link to the act_reg table is here if it helps: https://wiki.axiossystems.com/assyst10SP75Wiki/index.php/Installation:Database_Table_-_act_reg_(Action_Register)